# Spring MVC - How to get Controller level RequestMapping parameter inside Controller

Tags: spring-mvc

For example, if I had a Spring MVC Controller like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/{nickname}")
public class LoginController {
    //...controller code
}
```

I want a handle to the nickname inside my controller code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the path variable `{nickname}` at the controller level, and then use the `@PathVariable` annotation at the method parameter level.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/{nickname}")
public class LoginController {
    //...controller code

    @RequestMapping
    public String login(@PathVariable String nickname) {
        // Do something with nickname
    }
}
```

It may be more sensible to have part of the path fixed to identify the controller specifically - otherwise any request which doesn't get a more exact match may end up being sent to the `LoginController` which you may not want. For example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login/{nickname}")
public class LoginController {
```